# java RMI application. "_stub cannot be cast" error

Tags: java, rmi

This program worked fine before I organized the files into packages. The error message I get is as follows:

ClassCastException: a3.seneca.RemoteMethod_Stub cannot be cast to a3.seneca.RemoteMethod
(line 35)

My package structure is as follows (caps means directory):

-A3

--SERVER

----DataAccessServer

--SENECA

----RemoteMethodInterface

----RemoteMethod

--CLIENT

----DataAccessClient

The line the error message is referring to is this:

```
RemoteMethod rmHandler = (RemoteMethod) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:666/location");
```

Beforehand, in the DataAccessServer, I do this:

```
RemoteMethod rm = new RemoteMethod();
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:666/location", rm);
```

The steps to run are as follows:

console window #1:
rmiregistry 666

console window #2:
java a3\seneca*.java

java a3\server*.java

java a3\client*.java

rmic -v1.2 a3.seneca.RemoteMethod

java DataAccessServer

console window #3:

java a3.client.DataAccessClient

RemoteMethod_stub.class is put into the seneca directory. I've also tried copying it into the client directory after it's created. Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

-Dan

Comment: CORRECTION: javac ... *.java NOT java

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast the stub to the server class. You should be casting it to the remote interface. The stub isn't an instance of the server, it is an instance of the remote interface. That's how RMI works, and it is what the remote interface is for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The issue was, I had copied the interface (which extends remote) to client as well. Which should have been added to dependencies rather than copying.

The best way to do it is, export a jar of that interface. And add it to client dependencies and use it.

Hope it helps :)